# ASP.NET MVC4 simple membership doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

I have a MVC4 application that uses a sql server for data. I also have the simple membership provider and it's tables are stored in the same database and both use the same connection string:

```
<connectionStrings><add name="bazaConnectionString" connectionString="DataSource=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=baza;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=visualstudio;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I test the application in visual studio everything works normally, but when I published the project and attached it to IIS8 webserver(on same computer as the sql server) the simple membership doesn't work.

First I thought there was something wrong with the connection string but other functions from the application that use it work normally. But as soon as I click on something that uses the membership like Login it gives an error:

- WinException 0x80004005 File not found SqlException 0x80131904
- Network related or instance-specific error

Can anyone help me with this, otherwise I guess I will have to write my own user authorisation logic into every controller.

**Update:** After trying a few things it seems the problem is with the [Authorize] attribute and the accountController that visual studio generates. Because if I call WebSecurity methods, like Login, anywhere else it works.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is that your application is using another database for storing the simple membership information.

Browse the app_Data folder on your machine and if you see an .mdf file created there, you are for sure using a different db for that. This problem comes up when the asp.net application tries to search the localdb file in app_Data folder to attach but cannot find one. Reconfigure the simple membership provider to use the given connection string in that case.

Further, also ensure that you are not using asp.net configuration tools for creating users and roles as it will always create a localdb if no db is specified.

Comment: It's using the same database, I changed it in the file where WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection call is made.

Comment: have you checked the app_Data folder of your local project ?

Comment: I deleted the default database that was there.

Comment: Run your local application again and it will get created again, if it is so, let me know, I'll tell you how to get it fixed.

Comment: But I don't want it created, I am using one database for both the membership and other functions. That's why I changed the connection string.

Comment: I understand it but I want to ensure that it is the root cause of problem so I can suggest the exact fix